# Multiple users behavior inconsistent in Chromium snap on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: chromium, snap, 20.04, shortcuts, webapps

Just did a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. After updating packages and installing chromium snap

I signed in to my main account (I'll call it **profile 1**  *see [attached pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3cOf.png), top right window*)

```
Profile Path: /home/photon/snap/chromium/1143/.config/chromium/Default
```

I tried to place a website [shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFxlD.png) in the desktop to my launch my website directly

But whenever I tried to open the shortcut, it opened a different (generic) user window with the default new tab, not my signed in user nor my website (I'll call this **profile 2** *[attached pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3cOf.png), top left window*).

```
Profile Path: /home/photon/.config/chromium/Default
```

Whatever shortcuts I created in **profile 1** it just open a window on **profile 2**, a new window like clicking Ctrl + N

I decided to sign in to **profile 2** using a different account to test and  place a shortcut,

this time the [shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FczV.png) opened properly windowed instance of the website I wanted, it also displayed the website icon properly on the desktop and the app launcher, no workarounds needed

Now, this worked only for the shortcuts created through **profile 2** and opens automatically in **profile 2** , which path is:

```
Profile Path: /home/photon/.config/chromium/Default
```

Also, the chromium icon in the app launcher, opens **profile 1**

```
Profile Path: /home/photon/snap/chromium/1143/.config/chromium/Default
```

Note 1: I tried creating another test profiles one through profile 1 [bottom right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3cOf.png) and another through profile 2 [bottom left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3cOf.png)

Note 2: shortcut created through **profile 1**

`#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=‎‫Dashboard ‹ المرصد — WordPress‬‎
Exec=/snap/chromium/1143/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id=hdaffjkmdkmlhclgajaoglfdfdnekfma
Icon=chrome-hdaffjkmdkmlhclgajaoglfdfdnekfma-Default
StartupWMClass=crx_hdaffjkmdkmlhclgajaoglfdfdnekfma`

Shortcut created through **profile 2**

`#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=‎‫الرئيسية › المرصد — ووردبريس‬‎
Exec=/snap/chromium/1143/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id=hkpaiaaolchnaojdcmflgldhaopicfpa
Icon=chrome-hkpaiaaolchnaojdcmflgldhaopicfpa-Default
StartupWMClass=crx_hkpaiaaolchnaojdcmflgldhaopicfpa`

Comment: Please consider reporting a bug at launchpad.net.

Comment: Done that
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1877463